# Scale database that receives streaming data with small resources

Tags: database, mongodb, database-design, bigdata, scalability

My use case is the following: I run about 60 websockets from 7 data sources in parallel that record stock tickers (so time-series data). Currently, I'm writing the data into a mongodb that is hosted on a Google Cloud VM such that every data source has its own collection and all collections are hosted inside the same database.

However, the database has grown to 0.6 GB and ~ 10 million rows after only five days of data. I'm pretty new to such questions, but I have a feeling that this is not a viable long-term solution. I will never need all of the data at once, but I need all of the data in order to query by date / currency. However, as I understood those queries might become impossible once the dataset is bigger than my RAM, is that true?

Moreover, this is a research project, but unfortunately I'm currently not able to use a university cluster, therefore I'm hosting the data on a private VM. However, this is subject to a budget constraint, and highly performant machines quickly become very expensive. That's why I'm questioning my design choice. Currently, I'm thinking of either switching to another kind of database, but fear that I'm running into the same issues again, or exporting the database once per week / month / whatever to CSV and wiping out. This would be quite a hastle though and I'm also scared of losing data.

So my question is, how can I design this database such that I can subset the data per one of the keys (either datetime or ticker_id) even when the database grows larger than my machine's RAM? Diskspace is not an issue.

Comment: Of course you can store more data than your RAM. It's recommended to keep indexes in RAM for performance reasons but even this is not mandatory if you can compromise with slower responses. Your data is stored on disk. As long as ssd has enough capacity you are fine.

Answer (score 1):

On top of what Alex Blex already commented about storage and performance.

Query response time,in 5 days you have close to 10M rows, will worsen as data set grows. You can look at [sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-data-partitioning/) to break the table down to reasonable chunks and still have acees to all data for query purpose.

Comment: Thank you for the remark. Queries are already quite slow. I added a new column "date" to all collections with the goal to shard the data by it. It's probably not the most elegant solution to add another column, but would it be an acceptable solution? It would allow me to shard the data into chunks of roughly 100mb. I already have timestamps in every database, but because of the different data sources they're not always in the same format (some are timestamps and some are datetime), could it still make sense to use the available information or can the additional column be disregarded cost-wise?